# java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line: You must supply a layout_width attribute

Tags: android, android-fragments

**What I am doing ::**

1. I am using **[THIS-LIBRARY](http://av.victorhaggqvist.com/2013/04/s&.html)**
2. I have a main activity which has a drawer that hosts fragments(I
   have 5 fragments)
3. Among them one of the fragment i have implemented the above library
   for a sliding layer(ps: using this library because i am not using
   sherlock-lib)

**What is happening:**

1. On loading the fragment that has this library i get the log as shown
2. How to resolve this, library clearly states i can be used with
   fragments as it is treated a any other view(read in comments
   section)

---

**fragment_whats_hot.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonOpen"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:text="OPEN" />

    <com.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer
        xmlns:slidingLayer="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.slidinglayersample"
        android:id="@+id/slidingLayer1"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/layer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <!--
        slidingLayer:shadowDrawable="@drawable/sidebar_shadow"
        slidingLayer:shadowWidth="@dimen/shadow_width"
        slidingLayer:offsetWidth="@dimen/offset_width"
        slidingLayer:stickTo="auto|right|left|middle"
        slidingLayer:closeOnTapEnabled="true">
        -->

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#14ad8f" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/swipeText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:drawablePadding="15dip"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="80dp"
                android:textColor="#074035"
                android:textSize="17sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonClose"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
                android:onClick="buttonClicked"
                android:text="CLOSE" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </com.slidinglayer.SlidingLayer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**WhatsHotFragment.java**

```
public class WhatsHotFragment extends Fragment {

    public WhatsHotFragment(){}

    private SlidingLayer mSlidingLayer;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_whats_hot, container, false);

        // getPrefs();
        bindViews(rootView);
        initState();

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * View binding
     * @param rootView 
     */
    private void bindViews(View rootView) {
        mSlidingLayer = (SlidingLayer) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slidingLayer1);
    }

    /**
     * Initializes the origin state of the layer
     */
    private void initState() {
        // Sticks container to right or left
        LayoutParams rlp = (LayoutParams) mSlidingLayer.getLayoutParams();
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        mSlidingLayer.setLayoutParams(rlp);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonOpen:
            if (!mSlidingLayer.isOpened()) {
                mSlidingLayer.openLayer(true);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.buttonClose:
            if (mSlidingLayer.isOpened()) {
                mSlidingLayer.closeLayer(true);
            }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="@color/list_background"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Log:**

```
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 5917
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917): java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #14: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:492)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5960)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:6129)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:1225)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:1062)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.generateLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.java:82)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:757)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.WhatsHotFragment.onCreateView(WhatsHotFragment.java:23)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-24 19:13:27.951: E/AndroidRuntime(5917):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You didn't set the dimensions for your `buttonOpen` Button.

Comment: @DerGolem .... Yep ! ... That was the mistake .... i didn't notice that ... I guess my brain is not ticking .... need to refresh :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is rather straightforward:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #14: You must supply a layout_width attribute.
```

This means that you have an XML element in a layout file that needs an `android:layout_width` attribute, and you do not have one.

From the stack trace, this appears to be from `fragment_whats_hot.xml`. You will see that line #14 is in:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOpen"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:onClick="buttonClicked"
    android:text="OPEN" />
```

And, as the error message indicates, you do not have an `android:layout_width` attribute. Nor do you have an `android:layout_height` attribute. Please add them to your layout for this widget, and any other widgets or containers that need them... such as your other `Button`.

Comment: I being so dumb didn't notice that  ..... Thanks for answer and clear explanation !